# boostrap issues on the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>JuiceBox</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Html looks fine when checked locally but once uploaded to the server, the bootstrap doesn't work. I've used SASS does it have anything to do with it? Please help.

Comment: FYI, You shouldn't change your original question code after an each answer or comment is given. It will confuse people in the future when they view your question and try to understand how it was answered.

Comment: My problem is still the same.

Comment: The point is, people can see the progression of the answers based on your *original code*. If you want to get it fixed, posting a link or making a jsfiddle will help.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap needs Jquery to work on, Please add Jquery before bootstrap to make bootstrap run

Comment: Jquery should be loaded even before css file of bootstrap

Comment: Your loading `bootstrap.min.js` twice. Once before jQuery and once after. Remove the one before.

Comment: Jquery does not need to be loaded before any CSS, only before javascript  requiring jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Add a space between the 'rel="stylesheet" href..'

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And remove the spaces of the 'scrip'  and 't' in:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></scrip   t>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my code doesn't have spaces. It just happened when I was formatting it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script to import jquery instead of yours, I am sure it will work;

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading 2 versions of jQuery

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`
and 
`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">`. Remove version 1.11.3.

Secondly, your bootstrap CSS is not loading at all:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

because it is considered insecure content due to it being http instead of https. Change it to

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">`.

Also you were loading a different version of bootstrap.min.js (3.3.4 vs 3.3.7) Than what the css is.